# create negated regex expression for sed

Tags: regex, sed

If I have the string:

```
"ff","dd"dd","aa"
```

And I want to change any " that is not captured by the regex to x:

```
("(?=,))|((?<=,)")|(^")|("$)
```

Currently, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/OKFyUX/1) matches all `"` chars that I do not want to be replaced, and the result is `xffx,xdd"ddx,xaax`.

How do I obtain a result like `"ff","ddxdd","aa"`?

Comment: The regexp you posted appears to be a PCRE. sed doesn't work with PCREs, it works with BREs and some seds have a `-E` option to support EREs. So it's not clear what you mean by `not captured by the regexp` with a PCRE and sed when how sed interprets the regexp you posted isn't going to be as you intended and is in fact undefined behavior per POSIX since it contains repetition metachars at the start of regexp segments. So, please [edit] your question to  clarify what you're really trying to do and include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU sed with

```
sed 's/\b"\b/x/g' file
```

The pattern will match `"` when it is enclosed with alphanumeric chars. See an online `sed` demo:

```sh
s='"ff","dd"dd","aa"'
sed 's/\b"\b/x/g' <<< "$s"
# => "ff","ddxdd","aa"
```

Or, you may replace each `"` that is preceded and followed by a char other than a comma:

```sh
sed ':a; s/\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)/\1x\2/; ta' file
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/zSSz5n). Here:

- `:a` - sets a label at the current position
- `s/\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)/\1x\2/` - matches and captures any char but `,` into Group 1, then matches a `"` char, and then matches and captures any char but `,` into Group 2 and then replaces the match with Group 1 + `x` + Group 2
- `ta` - upon a successful match, loops back to the `a` label position.

Comment: Can I enhance the GNU command below to include a space or an alphanumeric character?  sed 's/\b"\b/x/g' file